# invalidpipeargument: '[object object']: error showing

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

So I am relatively new to Ionic and Firebase, and I am trying to display user data that already exists in Firebase. 
Here is the error that I am getting:

```
invalidpipeargument: '[object object']: error showing.
```

I do know what the issue is after looking at other questions similar to mine. It seems I cannot assign the async function as `database.object` does not return an observable. So I have tried to add `.valueChanges();` to make it an observable, but I believe this is clashing with the `angularfireobject` as that is already assigned to the variable `profile.data` so this would not work.

I have also tried this:

```
// get (): AngularFireObject<any[]>{
        //return this.afDatabase.list`/profile/${data.uid}`;
        //}
```

If you point me in the right direction that would be great.
Here is my code:

.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Profile } from '../../model/profile';
import { DEFAULT_INTERPOLATION_CONFIG } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {

  profileData: AngularFireObject<Profile>
    // get (): AngularFireObject<any[]>{
    //return this.afDatabase.list`/profile/${data.uid}`;
    //}

  constructor(private afAuth:AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, 
    public navCtrl: NavController, private toast: ToastController) {

  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
   this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data =>{

    if (data && data.email && data.uid){
      this.toast.create({
        message: `Welcome to MatchMyFighter ${data.email}`,
        duration: 3000,
      }).present();

     // this.profileData = this.afDatabase.object(`profile/${data.uid}`)
     this.profileData = this.afDatabase.object(`/profile/${data.uid}`).valueChanges();;
    }

    else{
      this.toast.create({
        message:`could not autenticate`,
        duration:3000
      }).present;
    }
   })
  }



}
```

.html

```
<p>
    Username: {{(profileData | async)?.username}}
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `valueChanges()` converts the `AngularFireObject<Profile>` to an observable.
You have to change the type to `Observable<Profile>` like so:

```
profileData: Observable<Profile>;

constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { } // other stuff emitted ...

ionViewDidLoad() {
    // ...
    this.profileData = this.db.object<Profile>(`/profile/${data.uid}`).valueChanges();
    // ...
}
```